# EF migration using multiple Contexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have looked through the other posts here on So about this, and am still having an issue.  I only have one application that uses multiple contexts so I don't have to use it a lot and last time I finally had it figured out, I didn't write it down, so bad on my part.

My Context.cs file is as follows:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace EventTracking.Models
{
    public class ContextMain : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }

        public ContextMain()
            : base({CONTENT REMOVED)
        {
        }
    }

    public class ContextReport : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }

        public ContextReport()
            : base({CONTENT REMOVED})
        {
        }
    }
}
```

My solution structure of my project is as follows:

```
-EventTracking (Solution name)
  -EventTracking (Project name)
    -Migrations_Main
      Configuration.cs
    -Migrations_report
      Configuration.cs
```

I am now trying to alter the Events model in the ContextMain context and am constantly being presented with the "The migration configuration type '______' was not found in the assembly 'EventTracking'

I have tried the following:

```
add-migration -configuration Eventtracking.Migrations_Main.Configuration "Alter Event"
add-migration -configuration Migrations_Main.Configuration "Alter Event"
add-migration -configuration Configuration "Alter Event"
```

The first two present an "configuration type could not be found" error.  Last one presents a "More than one migration configuration type 'Configuration' was found" error.

I then tried:

```
add-migration -configurationtypename Eventtracking.Migrations_Main.Configuration "Alter Event"
add-migration -configurationtypename Migrations_Main.Configuration "Alter Event"
add-migration -configurationtypename Configuration "Alter Event"
```

All three resulted in the "configuration type not found" error.

What irritatingly simple thing am I missing here??

Comment: That will happen with namespace typos and few other things [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001525/entity-framework-the-migrations-configuration-type-was-not-be-found-in-the-ass).