# When I am trying to add a migration, I got an error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I get this error:

> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'AppointmentScheduling' (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration)

Comment: So did you try Enable-Migrations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework - The migrations configuration type was not be found in the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001525/entity-framework-the-migrations-configuration-type-was-not-be-found-in-the-ass)

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a migration dependency package or have problems with the configuration, you can try the following changes：

install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

startup configuration：

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDBContextName>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

application.json:

```
 "connectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnections": "Data Source=Your Db;Initial Catalog=PracticaApiSecurity;Integrated Security=True"
  },
```

If there are still problems, can you publish your csproj file and your db configuration content?